# All portrait pictures are upside down

Tags: camera, photos

All pictures that I take in portrait mode with the stock camera app are upside down. I assume this is because when I take them I still hold my phone like a camera, not like a mobile phone.

I could use Camera 360 which has the option to adjust the orientation. It takes a couple of seconds to start up and is generally too bloated for my taste, though. Is there either a way to fix the orientation in the stock app or a more lightweight alternative that has this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use [Camera ICS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.cameraics&hl=en) which has all the features I need.